# Question on what role this infinitive plays in the sentence?

Tags: infinitives

> I am going **to study.**

Does "to study" act as an adverb, a direct object, or something else?  My gut feeling says adverb.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's just call it a complement. It's a complement of the [catenative verb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)

Comment: @user178049: But isn't it still a "complement" in *I am going **to work*** regardless of whether ***to*** is a preposition (work is where I'm going) or an infinitive marker (work is what I will be doing)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean just call it a complement when we are not sure whether it's an object or adverb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's often referred to as a 'catenative complement' in this situation..

Comment: @Araucaria Man: John Lawler seems to be referring to this construction where he says [*they are **subordinate clauses** and they **function as nouns** in the sentence*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184320/do-the-ing-and-to-infinitive-verbs-that-follow-catenative-verbs-always-take-t#comment382815_184320). Dunno if this question is a duplicate of that one though.

Comment: Remember that 'going to' is a standard signal of a future activity. Works in other languages like Spanish and French, too. When you don't know how to form the future tense of a verb, you say "I'm going to ABC" where 'to ABC' is any standard infinitive.

Comment: I'm confused by the comments.  There are several ways to parse this.  "am going to" means "will", as in "I will study".  "Study is a verb.  "Going" could mean traveling somewhere, and "to" mean "for the purpose of" or "in order to", so again, "study" would be a verb.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence 'I am going to study", "to study" acts as the verb in fact. 'I' is the subject and as far as " To be going to" is concerned, it plays itself the role of an auxiliary verb expressing the action in a very near future. In consequence, there is no complement in this sentence, which solely composed of a subject and a verb, lacks to be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

"To study" might seem like a dependent adverbial clause, if you are going for the purpose of studying.

Or the sentence might be employing the infinitive "to study" as main verb preceded by the future construct, be + going + infinitive. [I am, you/we/they are, he/she/it is. . .going to study.]

Sources:
[Is "am going" a verb phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42961/is-am-going-a-verb-phrase)

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_going-to.htm